# Use qml+QQuickView as a splash screen NOT working

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to add a splash screen to my c++/qt/qml applicaiton. I added the following codes:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->setSource(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/Splash.qml")));
    view->show();


   engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

   view->close();
   app.exec();

   return 0;
```

}

And the Splash.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Item {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    BusyIndicator {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 100
        running: true
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("splash screen... " + x + " " + y + " " + width + "x" + height)
            visible=true
        }
    }
}
```

When the application was starting, the message:"qml: splash screen... 270 190 100x100" was printed, but the QQuickWindow is just in white color. The main window for main.qml can work correctly. I tried to load an image in the Splash.qml,but same problem. And, I can NOT make it to be a frameless window using QQuickView::setWindowFlags. I'm working on win7 64bits OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easy in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: false
    x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2;
    y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2;

    Window {
        id: splashWindow
        width: 300
        height: 200
        visible: true
        x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2;
        y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2;
        flags: Qt.SplashScreen;
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "green";
        }

        ProgressBar {
            id: progressBar
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            anchors.margins: 20
            value: 0.01
        }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 50
            repeat: true
            running: true
            onTriggered: {
                progressBar.value += 0.01
                if(progressBar.value >= 1.0) {
                    timer.stop();
                    mainWindow.visible = true;
                    splashWindow.destroy();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```